# How to get f1 score in fasttext

Tags: multiclass-classification, fasttext

I am following the tutorial:

https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#our-first-classifier

I have a multiclass data with 26 labels. What does P@1 and R@1 means ?

If I have to get F1-score correspondingly, how can I get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P@1 and R@1 are respectively precision and recall when the model is called to predict the single most likely class.

*In some contexts (web information retrieval, recommender systems), it makes more sense that the model predicts k multiple classes and therefore we are interested in evaluating P@k and R@k.*

In the case in question (prediction of a class among 26), you can compute micro F1-score by inserting the values ​​of P@1 and R@1 in formula:

```
F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

To understand the differences between micro F1, macro F1... read [scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html).

In any case, if your goal is to train a model that maximizes the value of F1, you can let fastText handle the training through [Automatic hyperparameter optimization](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/autotune.html).

Comment: Does this also mean accuracy is same as precision and recall ?

Then the F1-Score would also be same.

Comment: As you can see in the same tutorial, they are different metrics with different values. Read this to understand better: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/accuracy-vs-f1-score-6258237beca2